# How do I get the first weekday of the month?

Tags: c#, date, calendar

I'm looking to reset a variable on the first weekday of the month, but I have not found a method to do this in C#.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  This is not to be confused with the first Monday of the week.  Before you mark this question "Duplicate", READ the question!

Comment: Of what month? Given a DateTime or what?

Comment: *Voting to **reopen***: While I'm not opposed to this being *a* duplicate (or otherwise defending this question), it is *not a duplicate* of that question or the question the 'duplicate' was already marked as a duplicate for.. This question asks how to Find the *First Weekday in a Month*. The 'duplicate' asks to Find [the datetime of] the *First Monday in a given Week*. The first Weekday of a month is *not* necessarily (or often?) the same as the first Monday of the week that starts the month.

Comment: (The code in the linked question can be used to construct a solution, where `DayOfWeek` is a useful property to look up; but the question is still *not* a duplicate.)